# Parse binary CSV file in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, parsing, encoding

This should have been such an easy thing... buy I can't for the life of me figure out how to parse a CSV file that doesn't seem to have a specific encoding.

```
File.open(Rails.root.join('data', 'mike/test-csv.csv'), 'rb') { |f| f.read }
=> "ID,\x00Q\x00u\x00a\x00n\x00t\x00i\x00t\x00y\n\x006\x00e\x005\x004\x009\x001\x00e\x007\x00-\x007\x00f\x001\x005\x00-\x004\x001\x007\x00d\x00-\x00a\x004\x000\x003\x00-345\x00,\x00\x005\x000\x00.\x000\x000\x000\x000\x000\x000\x000\x000\x00\n"
```

Here's a gist of it, can't figure out a way to post the specific CSV.

All I get from checking the encoding of the file is that it's in binary format, any thoughts on how I could get it into a normal csv?

Note: This is a downloaded CSV so converting it to another encoding via opening it in excel and exporting (or something like that) is not an option :)

Thanks!

**Updating with attempted solution 1:**

```
path = Rails.root.join('data', 'mike/test-csv.csv')
CSV.read(path, {:headers  => true, :encoding => 'utf-8'}).each do |d| 
  puts d 
end
Result: 6e5491e7-7f15-417d-a403-345,50.00000000
```

While this is correct, it ONLY works with `puts`, for example:

```
CSV.read(path, {:headers  => true, :encoding => 'utf-8'}).map { |row| row }
=> [#<CSV::Row "ID":"\u00006\u0000e\u00005\u00004\u00009\u00001\u0000e\u00007\u0000-\u00007\u0000f\u00001\u00005\u0000-\u00004\u00001\u00007\u0000d\u0000-\u0000a\u00004\u00000\u00003\u0000-345\u0000" "\u0000Q\u0000u\u0000a\u0000n\u0000t\u0000i\u0000t\u0000y":"\u0000\u00005\u00000\u0000.\u00000\u00000\u00000\u00000\u00000\u00000\u00000\u00000\u0000">]

CSV.read(path, {:headers  => true, :encoding => 'utf-8'}).map(&:to_s)
=> ["\u00006\u0000e\u00005\u00004\u00009\u00001\u0000e\u00007\u0000-\u00007\u0000f\u00001\u00005\u0000-\u00004\u00001\u00007\u0000d\u0000-\u0000a\u00004\u00000\u00003\u0000-345\u0000,\u0000\u00005\u00000\u0000.\u00000\u00000\u00000\u00000\u00000\u00000\u00000\u00000\u0000\n"]
```

It's unfortunately still not the correct string :(

**Final Solution (via @ashmaroli below):**

```
path = Rails.root.join('data', 'mike/test-csv.csv')
csv_text = ''

File.open(path, 'r') do |csv|
  csv.each_line do |line|
    csv_text << line.gsub(/\u0000/, '')
  end
end

CSV.parse(csv_text, headers:true).map do |row| row end
```

Result:

```
[#<CSV::Row "ID":"6e5491e7-7f15-417d-a403-345" "Quantity":"50.00000000">]
```

[Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/mikefogg/4658171df151c625e5bae58717bd1282)

[Download Example CSV File](https://nofile.io/f/ZgvXFbAyNkg/test-csv.csv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
path = Rails.root.join('data', 'mike/test-csv.csv')
file = ""

File.open(path, 'r') do |csv|
  csv.each_line do |line|
    file << line.gsub(/\u0000/, '')
  end
end
print file
print file.inspect # same as above just wraps the string in a
                   # single line with "\n" chars
```

Comment: thanks for the comment! Unfortunately, this doesn't work :( I'll update my post with the results

Comment: if the `puts` command outputs the right string, then perhaps the following should work as well: **`CSV.read(path, {:headers  => true, :encoding => 'utf-8'}).map(&:to_s)`**

Comment: appreciate the effort! Just pasted that output as an edit to my post. Seems to still have an encoding on it. The gist I pasted in there should have the same encoding (if the github gist maintains it) if you want to test that in irb?

Comment: Also added a link to the actual file in there too!

Comment: added another update.. this time, using `File` and `gsub`

Comment: that's the one! Thank you!