# Parsing binary file upon csv file

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, struct, binaryfiles

i would like to parse binary file with scheme from csv file.

csv:

```
    Hex Addr    Byte       Package  ... Tlm Type Tlm Conversion (EU/lsb)                                    Eng. Units (EU)
0      0x420    32.0   COMMAND_TLM  ...    uint8                     1.0  0/OK 1/BAD_APID 2/BAD_OPCODE 3/BAD_DATA 7/NO_C...
1      0x421    33.0   COMMAND_TLM  ...    uint8                     1.0  0/OK 1/BAD_APID 2/BAD_OPCODE 3/BAD_DATA 7/NO_C...
2      0x422    34.0   COMMAND_TLM  ...    uint8                     1.0                                               none
3      0x423    35.0   COMMAND_TLM  ...    uint8                     1.0                                               none
4      0x424    36.0   COMMAND_TLM  ...    uint8                     1.0                                               none
..       ...     ...           ...  ...      ...                     ...                                                ...
721    0x9c9  1481.0  EXT_TRACKER2  ...   uint16                     1.0                                               none
722    0x9cb  1483.0  EXT_TRACKER2  ...    uint8                     1.0  0/NEW_DATA_IN 1/COMMITTING 2/COMMITTED 3/EXTRA...
723    0x9cc  1484.0  EXT_TRACKER2  ...    uint8                     1.0                                               none
724    0x9cd  1485.0  EXT_TRACKER2  ...    uint8                     1.0                                               none
725    0x9ce  1486.0  EXT_TRACKER2  ...    uint8                     1.0                                               none
```

columns from csv:

```
Index(['Hex Addr', 'Byte', 'Package', 'Mnemonic', 'Short Description',
       'Tlm Type', 'Tlm Conversion (EU/lsb)', 'Eng. Units (EU)'],
      dtype='object')
```

Additional info:

- Time information in the binary file is in TAI seconds from January 1st 2000, 00:00:00
- ECI frame of reference is J2000
- The size of a data chunk is 2068 bytes

so far i read the file and am struck upon next steps:

```
n [61]: def read_data(): 
    ...:     with open('telemetry.bin','rb') as file: 
    ...:         data = file.read() 
    ...:     return data 
    ...:      
    ...:                             

In [62]: len(data)                   
Out[62]: 7510976
```

I was thinking about creating a struct class with fields from csv file, and iterate over binary file with pattern from newly created struct object. But i think my approach is missing some things. Especially I don't which columns from the csv should be encoded into struct object.

Also I am struggling with question - is the first data chunk is equal to data[:2068]

If you have any resources upon this topic I would be thankful. I know there is a lot of question, but I am very eager to finally accomplish this task - it has been almost 4 years know since I received it.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're trying to do here as the example you give is neither binary nor csv - rather it appears to be a columnar text format. Please clarify, are you parsing a binary file that you were given, trying to produce a binary file from the above output, or something else?

Comment: trying to parse binary file I were given

Comment: i was thinking about someting similar as i found this SO question with Ruby:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46428471/parse-binary-csv-file-in-ruby

Comment: Perhaps show a dump of what the first few records look like as hex.

Comment: Out[66]: b'\n\x00\x00\x07\x08\x01\x0b\xe7\x08\xc3' - thats the data[:10]

Comment: ? how can that encompass the 8-9 columns of data that a record appears to have above? FWIW, that looks more like a binary code excerpt to me, what with the 0xC3 (ret) at the end, and all.

Answer (score 1):

> The size of a data chunk is 2068 bytes

What you have is a binary file of 2068-byte *records*, and a text file (that you called "CSV") describing the record layout.

I would first parse the record layout into a tuple of 725 field descriptors.  Each descriptor would be a tuple of length, mnemonic, and (for good measure) type. Each data record can be represented in memory with a dictionary (keyed by the mnemonic).

Then, iterate over the input, reading one 2068-byte record at a time.  For each record, do ... something to process each record.

I haven't used it, but I would try the [struct module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html?highlight=struct#module-struct) in the Python standard library.  I think that's what you want.  You might have to `eval` some Python to apply the data from your record-descriptor tuple, and it might not be blindingly fast, but it looks like it will get you there.

Otherwise, iterate over the record descriptor, copying `length` bytes to an integer, and assigning that integer to the dictionary. You might find it convenient to write a function that processes an individual field (populates one dictionary element), and pass that function to Python's standard `map`.

What you do with each record — each dictionary — is obviously up to you.

Comment: Thanks, your reply is very helpful. I would like only to ask what do you mean by:

`descriptor would be a tuple of length, mnemonic, and (for good measure) type`

is this a reference to a df.columns? From where then I take length and type - there are no such columns in df.

Comment: Your text file describes each field with `'Hex Addr', 'Byte', 'Package', 'Mnemonic'`, etc. That's what I meant by descriptor: a metadata record that tells you how to interpret each record.  You're right, length is implied by the difference between two offsets, or you can derive it as a "property" of the type.  It appears, for example, that `uint8` is 1 byte. I bet there's a small number of such types, and that their lengths are consistent throughout.